# Is it possible to simplify $\frac{n + 1}2\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\left(1+2\cos\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right)^s$ for integers $n\geq2$ and $s\geq1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Is it possible to simplify this trigonometric sum?

$$ \frac{n + 1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \sin^2 \frac{k \pi}{n + 1}\left(1 + 2 \cos \frac{k \pi}{n + 1}\right)^s $$

$ n \ge 2 \in \mathbb{Z} $, $ s \ge 1 \in \mathbb{Z} $.

The sum should always be an integer, would love to be able to calculate it in just the integers.

Wonder if we can interpret this as some kind of sum of roots for some Chebyshev polynomials.

Context - if that matters:

This come up from an attempt to compute an analytic solution for this coding challenge.
https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-ways-to-stay-in-the-same-place-after-some-steps/

In particular, this formula comes calculating the matrix power after diagonalizing the tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix.

The floating point numbers involved in the formula make it impractical to use, but if we find a route that doesn't involve them, then that would be enough. Of course, we have to keep the complexity advantage in order to be useful.

Comment: As wrtten, this sum is not an integer.

Comment: Hi Cecilia! I'm the person from the "36ms" post on Leetcode. Welcome to MSE (+1) :). It might be worth mentioning that you're specifically interested in this value modulo a large prime, and the "walks in a graph" interpretation could be relevant too if you're looking for an answer in general, not only via this formula. Also that [this](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL18/Felsner/felsner2.html) paper also discusses these numbers, and some of them appear in OEIS as A024537, A005207, A094286, A094287, A094288. I think your formula should start with $\frac{2}{n + 1}$ but otherwise I agree!

Comment: If I understand your motivation correctly, you'd like to have a practical and efficient way to write a program to compute these "bounded Motzkin numbers" modulo $p$, for $s$ on the order of $500$ and $n$ on the order of $250$ (which performs better than the $\mathcal O(s^2)$ dynamic programming approach). If that's right, perhaps it's worth emphasising this a little more. If I've got that wrong and you're generally just interested in abstract properties of this formula, that's fine too and you can leave your post as is!

Answer (score 3):

Let $$a_k=\cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{n+1}\right)$$ and replace the sine to write
$$F_s=\frac {n+1}2\Bigg( \sum_{k=1}^n (1+2a_k)^s-\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2(1+2a_k)^s\Bigg)$$ and, for integer $s$ use the binomial expansion to face sums of powers of cosines in arithmetic progression (which are known).

Do not forget that you can linearize the powers of the cosine function.

If $n$ is even
$$\cos^n(x)=\frac 1{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\frac n2}\binom{n}{k} \cos ( (2 k-n)x)+\frac 1{2^{n}}\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}$$

If $n$ is odd
$$\cos^n(x)=\frac 1{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\frac {n-1}2}\binom{n}{k} \cos ( (2 k-n)x)$$

All of that would lead to a quite simple result for $F_s$ (try for $n=2,3,4$ to see an ovious pattern).

Not very surprizing, the result involves    Motzkin numbers